Dependencies version clashing
I have a theoretical question today. What happens when I have same dependency in many projects in one solutions, but they are in different versions? Can it cause problems in the future? Is it possible, that program will crash because of that in some edge case (using some method that is not available in old dependency or something)? Or maybe .NET handles it somehow and it's 100% safe to use different versions?
Let's say I have App.sln and 2projects in it - Presentation.csproj and Infrastructure.csproj.
I've added Newtonsoft.Json to Presentation.csproj in version 9.01, but many months later, I've also added Newtonsoft.Json to Infrastructure.csproj, but now in version 13.0.3 (never ever again updated any of those).
Yes I know it's bad to not keep up to date because of vulnerabilities, and I know that best way is to update every where to same newest version, but that is not my question

What kind of dependency is this? An assembly-reference? A NuGet package reference? A project-reference? A COM component interop reference? A web-service-reference? Etc?

You need to learn about SemVer and how potentially-breaking-changes are indicated by  incrementing the major-version component.

@Dai I was thinking about NuGet package reference but answer can be elaborated to many cases :D

Yeah I know that major version can break a code etc - But that's not the problem here - I am wondering if using different version in different projects can somehow change something (I am not talking about updating version to new major one in code that can use it)

"I am wondering if using different version in different projects can somehow change something" - I suggest you try it and find out and see what happens. Depending on your project you may get a runtime error during assembly-loading, or a strong-naming error, or VS/NuGet will add <bindingRedirect> for you so it won't fail, but it might break subtly without you realising it.

You might want to read John Skeets articles on versioning.

What happens when I have same dependency in many projects in one solutions, but they are in different versions?

Either one of the projects will fail to load the dependency since the versions do not match, or it will load one version (typically the latest) of the library and use that for both projects.

Can it cause problems in the future? Is it possible, that program will crash because of that in some edge case (using some method that is not available in old dependency or something)?

Yes, this can cause issues. If semantic versioning is used you should be able to assume that minor versions are backward compatible. But with major version changes there are most likely at least some breaking changes that can cause issues.

Or maybe .NET handles it somehow and it's 100% safe to use different versions?

Nothing is 100% safe. You always need to test your application.
If you control all of the projects the solution is quite simple, just update all of your libraries to use the same version, and use automated testing to help ensure the update did not break anything.
For third party projects the situation will be more difficult, and all potential solutions would have some tradeoffs, see the linked article for more details.
